# Outlook add-ins event handler

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, office365api, outlook-restapi

In outlook account open or outlook account signIn action ,Trigger this action on my outlook add-ins
I want to trigger some function in outlook add-ins when I open the outlook page

I was implement the event background sync from add-ins to outlook calendar , so i want this handler

In My outlook add-ins used Javascript language

Any thoughts about this please share me

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you please clarify your query? Do you want to trigger an event when you open an outlook account or sign in to it?

Comment: I want this every time page load outlook page  , Because sync the events from outlook add-ins to outlook calendar every page load

Comment: Any handler trigger in outlook page like  any page load or any page open(calendar tab open  , mail tab open) tab click trigger is available please share me

Comment: i want outlook add-ins some function execute without open outlook add-ins ,run the function using any generic event handlers or triggers  when i open the outlook mailbox

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is currently not present in outlook add-ins. Please go through the documentation to know more about the supported events. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

Answer (score 0):

Outlook add-ins are run under the context of Outlook items only, so you have got access to a particular Outlook item only. Here is what MSDN states for that:

> Outlook activates some types of add-ins if the message or appointment that the user is reading or composing satisfies the activation rules of the add-in. This is true for all add-ins that use the 1.1 manifest schema. The user can then choose the add-in from the Outlook UI to start it for the current item.

Also you may be interested in the event based action which is still not fully released to public (still in preview), see [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) for more information.

Finally, you may also post your suggestion to the [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) tech community page.